# Why is Moral holding a golden gun in Episode 7?

Tags: hamatora

In the last scene of episode 7,

> Moral was pointing a golden gun at Art.

But in the beginning of episode 8,

> Moral is seen to be holding a normal black gun.

Why is he holding a different gun? Does this have any implications to the story?
[image]

Comment: Probably an animation error or they realized this wasn't the best gun visually and decided to change it, but the previous episode was already out there, so they couldn't do anything about it. I'd look for differences in a DVD/Bluray version when it's out. They should fix it by then, but if it's not the same, then it might be deliberate.

Comment: [The Blu-ray volume that contains episodes 7 and 8 comes out on December 26.](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%9E%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9-3-%E5%88%9D%E5%9B%9E%E7%94%9F%E7%94%A3%E9%99%90%E5%AE%9A%E7%89%88-Blu-ray/dp/B00LGDUAWI/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1416353484&sr=8-10&keywords=%E3%83%8F%E3%83%9E%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9+blu-ray)